# MPEG-7 descriptors' implementation in OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, local-features, shape-analysis

I'm looking for implementation of MPEG-7 descriptors which are compatible with OpenCV's recent versions and containing "region-based shape descriptor ART(Angular Radial Transformation)".

I encountered an [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882521/opencv-mpeg7-descriptors) which had very informative answers:

[Link in one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882521/opencv-mpeg7-descriptors/5713222#5713222) was containing only the following descriptors:

- Color Structure Descriptor (CSD)
- Scalable Color Descriptor (SCD)
- GoF/GoP Color Descriptor (GoF/GoP)
- Color Layout Descriptor (CLD)
- Dominant Color Descriptor (DCD)
- Homogeneous Texture Descriptor (HTD)
- Edge Histogram Descriptor (EHD)
- Face Recognition Descriptor (FRD)

[Link in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882521/opencv-mpeg7-descriptors/1031946#1031946) was looking too outdated and wasn't containing documentation.

If there is another implementation I would like to go through it.

Thank you.